# Space efficiency of writing over temp data structures in java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, memory-efficient

using java for illustration, will the following code delete the previous instance of temp? or will it still be in memory for sometime until garbage collection takes care of it.

```
        String[] words = {"one", "two" ,"three", "four", "five"};

        for(String s: words){
            // writing over temp each time
            HashSet<Character> temp = new HashSet<Character>();
            for(Character c : s.toCharArray()){
                temp.add(c);
            }
            // do some computation with temp, afterwhich is no longer needed.
        }
```

In my mind I am thinking that once temp has been written over its deleted pretty much straight away, making it efficient. Am i correct?

if not, is there a more space efficient way of making a temp data structure?

I understand that different languages have different garbage collection implementation, so would like to mainly know for java, however if there is a general rule for all languages that i could follow, that would be great

Comment: Java will do garbage collection when it needs to.  There is no "general rule for all languages", as their memory models differ wildly.  Unless you are dealing with multi-gigabyte in-memory data structures, don't worry about it.

Comment: You are pre-optimizing this. It seems to me very unlikely that  making this more efficient will improve overall system performance

Comment: The answer to this question: "Yes"

Comment: One of the points of garbage collection is that space efficiency becomes far less of a concern.

Comment: Every time you call `toCharArray()` you’re creating a new `char[]` object and within “do some computation with temp” you surely create even more temporary objects. So why worry about that specific single object referenced by `temp`?

Answer (score 0):

--- edit ---

The code below is not correct. But as other have commented, you can use a BitSet

---

If you are just talking about characters between a and z, the most efficient way you can do this is to use a bitmask, like

```
public class CharBitMask {
  private int mask;
  public void add (char c) {
    mask = mask | (1 ^ ('a' - c));
  }
  public boolean contains (char c) {
    return mask & (1 ^ ('a' - c)) == 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) where you index by `ch - 'a'`.  There's probably need to roll your own.

Comment: Doesn’t even compile, due to the operator precedence between `&` and `==`, but also wrong in several regards. `(1 ^ ('a' - c))` should be `1 << 'a' - c` but even then, the result of `&` is not `1` but a bit at the specified position, so you should test `!= 0` instead. `public void add(char c) { mask |= 1 << 'a' - c; }  public boolean contains(char c) { return (mask & 1 << 'a' - c) != 0; }`. Yet another reason to use `BitSet` instead, which allows to use `set(c)` and `get(c)` and you’re done, obviously correct and supporting the entire `char` range.